# Mysql concat html different on two servers

Tags: html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to use CONCAT in this view:

```
  CONCAT ('<a href="" onclick="return top.GO.linkHandlers.GO_Projects_Model_Project([', pm_projects.id, '])">', pm_projects.id, '</a>') As `GO-id`,
```

On my local computer this works fine in phpmyadmin and gives this expected result:

```
  <a href="" onclick="return top.GO.linkHandlers.GO_Projects_Model_Project([190])">190</a>
```

But on the live server i get this:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;&quot; onclick=&quot;return top.GO.linkHandlers.GO_Projects_Model_Project([190])&quot;&gt;190&lt;/a&gt;
```

Why would it work fine on my local installation, but not on my live server?

Thanks for all help.

Comment: What language are you using to build the web page from the query? Something is doing HTML entity encoding of the results of the query.

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin to create a view.

The version that works is phpmyadmin 3.5.2.2

The version on the live server is phpmyadmin 3.3.7 (and that is the one that does not work)

I will be using PHP to create the web page, but the wrong encoding seem to be in the mysql table itself.

Comment: It's encoding the literal strings coming from the query, those parts don't come from the table. This seems like it's just a phpmyadmin display issue.

Comment: You are right, indeed. It works as expected in my web page. It just looked wrong in phpmyadmin. Thank you very much!